# What is this "< >" behind a method means?

Tags: c#

Like this:

```
var result1 = GetData<double>(someString);
var result2 = GetData<string>(someString);
```

What is this meant?

```
< >
```

How to return data?

```
public object GetData<Type>(string a)
{
    // How do I know I should return this...

    return 2.2;

    // or this?

    return "2.2";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing here is called Generics. You can read about them in detail at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx). In short, you can specify a `Type Parameter` along with your method. Based on the type, different code paths can be adopted. Read the link for examples and such.

In your particular case, the return type is independent of the type parameter. You are dealing with two different things. So, while returning, you can use any of those two statements.

```
return 2.2;
```

This will return a `long` 2.2. While the other statement will return a `string` which is `"2.2"`. Since your return type is `Object`, both are acceptable. Though you haven't said that in problem, what you're looking for is something like this:

```
//Your generic GetData method
public TEntity GetData<TEntity>(string arg1)
{
    var toReturn;
    //Do some calculations
    return (TEntity)toReturn;
}
```

Now, when you make a call like this:

```
var t = GetData<string>(string1);
```

variable `t` will hold a `string`. If you do a call like this:

```
var t = GetData<int>(string1);
```

variable `t` will hold and `int`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a type parameter for generic method.

Comment: You mean the type *argument*. The type *parameter* occurs at the declaration. (For example, `T` is a type parameter in the declaration for `List<T>`, but `string` is the type *argument* in the use of `List<string>`.)

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is **Generics**. These are type arguments into the method, which mean that the method/class can work with specific types in a type-safe manner rather than falling back to everything being `object` (which also has a performance impact with boxing/unboxing).

From the C# guide:

> Generics allow you to define type-safe data structures, without
>   committing to actual data types. This results in a significant
>   performance boost and higher quality code, because you get to reuse
>   data processing algorithms without duplicating type-specific code.

A few quick links:

- [.NET Generics in a Nutshell](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47850/NET-Generics-in-a-Nutshell)
- [An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

That symbol after a method called Generic Method. It will defer the type inference during runtime.

Your GetData may be rewritten as below provided that you control the calling method as

```
GetData<float>("2.2")
GetData<string>("2.2")


public static T GetData<T>(string a)
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(a, typeof(T));
        }
```